# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' with pywhatkit library

Tags: whatsapp, attributeerror

everybody!

This is my code:

```
import pywhatkit 

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+34*********","Buenas tardes",20,59)
```

And this is my error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Why? I don´t understand it

Comment: Can you share your python version?. Also, can you execute this on the console and share the complete trace? I've tested it on python3 venv needing only to install "python3-tk python3-dev" and I had no error". Is that the only code on your script?

Answer (score 1):

It was a small bug in version 4.5 of PyWhatKit, it was fixed in the newer version, use `pip install pywhatkit==4.6` to update it.